# Having trouble proving if two sets are equal or not

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to figure out how to prove if two sets are equivalent or not by using the laws and rules of set theory but I am having a hard time with questions involving algebraic expressions.

This is one of the questions I am struggling on from Grimaldi's Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics, Exercise 3.1 #6d.

$D = \{3r + 1 | r \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

$E = \{3s + 2 | s \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Determine if this statement is true or false:  $D = E$.

I know that this is the same as proving if $D \subseteq E \land E \subseteq D$ is true or false. I can disprove this statement by using a counterexample but my professor would prefer us to use the rules and laws of set theory to determine if it's true.

To prove this, I have to prove $D \subseteq E$ and $E \subseteq D$ are both true. Starting with the former:

Let $x \in D \Rightarrow x = 3r + 1$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I don't really know what to do from here though. The method my professor showed me was to try and transform the expression on the LHS to the one RHS but I'm not quite sure how I would apply this technique here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since $r,s$ are just symbols, you find that the construction of $D,E$ is the same so they have the same elements...

Comment: Warm welcome to mse. Interesting profile picture... to say the least

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the question. I've updated it now.

Comment: You might find some elements that are in $D$ and $E$ to see if you see a pattern.

Comment: I can compute the expression in $D$ by letting $r$ be an integer and set the expression in $E$ to that value and solve for the variable, $s$ in $E$ to show that this equality is false. But I am trying to solve it using the laws and rules of set theory and I'm not quite sure how to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

A basic axiom of set theory, called Extensionality, is that sets $D,E$ are equal iff they have the same member(s). More precisely, $D=E$ iff every $x$ either belongs to $D$ and to $E,$ OR doesn't belong to $D$ nor to $E$. So to prove $D\ne E$, it suffices to find an $x$ with $(x\in D$ and $x\not \in E)$ or  $(x\in E$ and $x\not \in D).$ For example, in your Q, $1=3\cdot 0+1\in D,$ but $1\not\in E$. Because if $1= 3s+2\in E$ with $s\in\Bbb Z$ then $-1/3=s\in\Bbb Z,$ which is absurd.